# The right way to do input validation in SQL for NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking at doing some input validation for my stored procedures in T-SQL. This is currently my method.

All attributes are NOT NULL without defaults at table creation.

```
DECLARE @rc INT
@rc = 0

IF value IS NULL

BEGIN 
SET @rc = -1
END

BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- WORK

IF @rc = 0
COMMIT
RETURN @rc

ELSE 
ROLLBACK
RETURN @rc
```

The problem with this method is that upon an insertion in the transaction, there will already be an error (assuming NULL input) for trying to insert the NULL attribute, and the application will never receive @rc. This is unwelcome because I have other input validation which returns different @rc's for different errors.

Some possible solutions:

1. Remove NOT NULL from table creation.
2. Just return @rc in the 'IF value IS NULL' and don't use transactions.

What's the best way to handle this kind of thing? I'm refactoring all of this and the previous dev used different styles for different procedures.

Comment: Look up TRY/CATCH

Comment: @pmbAustin Is this considered the best solution to input validation instead of creating your own return codes? I figured this would only be for other types of errors.

Comment: It's an opinion based question. I suggest you do all of your parameter validation at the top of your procedure, and if any of the values passed fail your validation, return @rc immediately. There's no point in beginning a transaction for something you know is going to error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using TRY/CATCH; it worked fine.